# Не выходит проверка на наличие в json нужного мне значения

Tags: javascript

Вот собственно сам код(я ещё новичок в js)

```
$('#saveVideoBtn').click(function(evt) {
  var cmo = document.getElementById("videoLink").value;

  var keks = JSON.parse('[{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.ustream.tv\/embed\/9600798"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.rt.com\/on-air\/embed\/"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.ustream.tv\/embed\/13659436"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.ustream.tv\/embed\/9948292"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/cabinet.glazok.kz\/embed\/v2\/?server=100-pSVOGsxeGuQkxVOnCv6GHk&amp;camera=393216&amp;width=&amp;height=&amp;lang=ru"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/5nn_vtDSBWo"},{"videoLink":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/21X5lGlDOfg"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=taD9hqwCb1o"},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/YAmqhZHb4lw"}]').videoLink;
  alert(keks[cmo]);
  console.log(keks);
  if ($.inArray(cmo, keks) != -1) {
    alert("kek");
  } else {
    return false;
    //$("#saveVideoBtn").prop("disabled", false);
    $('#updateCategoryForm').submit();
  }

});
```

Должен проверять уникальность по базе сравнивая input и значения с базы, о почему то совсем не хочет этого делать. Подскажите где косячу..

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать :)

```
 function searchInObj(o, f) { 
      return o.filter(function(o) {
           return Object.keys(o).some(function(k) {
                return o[k] == f ? o[k].includes(f) : null;
           })
      });
  }

   $('#saveVideoBtn').click(function(evt) {
      var cmo = document.getElementById("videoLink").value;

  var keks = JSON.parse('[{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.ustream.tv\/embed\/9600798"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.rt.com\/on-air\/embed\/"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.ustream.tv\/embed\/13659436"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.ustream.tv\/embed\/9948292"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/cabinet.glazok.kz\/embed\/v2\/?server=100-pSVOGsxeGuQkxVOnCv6GHk&amp;camera=393216&amp;width=&amp;height=&amp;lang=ru"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/5nn_vtDSBWo"},{"videoLink":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/21X5lGlDOfg"},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=taD9hqwCb1o"},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":""},{"videoLink":"https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/YAmqhZHb4lw"}]');

  if(searchInObj(keks, cmo).length === 0) {
          alert("kek");
          return false;
  } 


  alert(keks[cmo]);
  console.log(keks);

    //$("#saveVideoBtn").prop("disabled", false);
    $('#updateCategoryForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined получаю в консоли и кнопка не работает(

Comment: Передаёте строку или объект?

Comment: там php скрипт прямо вместо строки стоит и генерирует я так полагаю строку

Comment: Прошу прощения что отвечал долго, сбросьте весь код пожалуйста. Код рабочий, но вместо строки мы должны получить уже объект